# Node-Craigslist syntax for details

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I am using the package node-craigslist https://github.com/brozeph/node-craigslist, and am hoping that someone can help me with some syntax with the details method.
In his documentation, he gives the example

```
client
  .list()
  .then((listings) => client.details(listings[0]))
  .then((details) => {
    console.log(details);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

I currently have working the code to get the listings, but not the details. Below is my section of code where I retrieve the listings.

```
client
  .list(options)
  .then((listings) => {
      listings.forEach((listing) => {
            console.log(listing);
            searchResults.title[counter] = listing.title;
            searchResults.date[counter] = listing.date;
            searchResults.location[counter] = listing.location;
            searchResults.url[counter]   = listing.url;
            searchResults.price[counter]   = listing.price;
            counter++;
            if(counter === listings.length) {
                socket.emit('redirect'); //change to /results.ejs if done looping
            };
    });//end of listings foreach
  });
```

I have been trying to incorporate the details into my own code unsuccessfully. Does anybody have any knowledge on how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: is there an error you are getting?

Comment: I've tried something like  `.list(options)
  .then((listings) => client.details(listings){
   var allListings = listings;
   listings.forEach((listing) => {` at the top of my code and it errors that I'm missing a ) and if I add it in after the client.details, it says that { is unexpected. Very new to this sort of stuff so I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in a `listing` object into the method. In his example, he just grabs the most recent listings without any search options, then passes in the first listing from that array of listings. But you could obviously customize the search and the options.

```
client
  .list()
  .then((listings) => client.details(listings[0]))
  .then((details) => {
    console.log(details);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Depending on how the rest of your code is structured, you need to determine when to pass a specific listing. In my app that I built with this package, I make the initial search request that returns all the listings, and then when the user clicks on a listing for a search term, I make another request passing along that specific listing OBJECT and then it returns the details.

To be even more specific ...

1. On the client side the user searches, I emit that to the server then make the search request.
2. Once the request is finished I emit the results back to the client and then display the information to the user and store each listing object inside a custom data attribute inside each listing for later use.
3. Once the user clicks on a specific listing, I grab the object from the data-attribute and emit that to the server.
4. The server listens for that and makes the second DETAILS request using that listing object which is then emitted back to the clients browser.

Comment: I've gone ahead and begun to implement the solution you've suggest and I think its going to turn out much better than it would have with the old plan. A second query in a seperate function to view the results I think is much more elegant. Thanks.